# Custom + Method in Ruby String

Tags: ruby, string

I am trying to modify the Ruby String class, specifically the + method.  I want it to return a specific string, such that

```
 "a" + "b" => "custom_result"
```

Here's what I have:

```
class String

  def +(a)
    "custom_result"
  end

end
```

When I try to require this file in irb, "custom_result" is in my prompt, and I can't execute anything.  Any ideas?

Comment: What if you require this in another file, not IRB?

Comment: Just tried in rspec, and am getting expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, IRb uses the `String` class both to print the results and to parse what you type into it. If you mess with that, IRb breaks, that's not really surprising.