# Ruby custom string method?

Tags: ruby, string

How do I make this code more elegant? I have:

```
alpha = "lorem ipsum"
alpha = alpha + "\n" + "more text"
alpha = alpha + "\n" + "look I'm woody, howdy howdy howdy"
#etc
```

I would like:

```
alpha.puts "lorem ipsum"
alpha.puts "more text"
alpha.puts "look I'm woody, howdy howdy howdy"
# etc
```

or, perhaps, `alpha.append` as it is not taken. I attempted:

```
class String
  def append(apnd)
    self.to_s + "\n" + apnd
  end
end
```

but that doesn't modify it, only returns it. And I learned from searching you can't modify the self. I get the same problem with:

```
def apnd(a,b)
  a = a + "\n" + b
end
```

which I find very confusing as I thought Ruby passes the object by reference, rather than by value.

I saw "[Custom + Method in Ruby String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859571/custom-method-in-ruby-string)" and a couple other Stack Overflow posts.

---

Update:

Aha, for the `apnd` method I can follow "['pass parameter by reference' in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161510/pass-parameter-by-reference-in-ruby)" but that means I can't have `apnd(alpha, "stuff")`, it would have to be `apnd(:alpha, "stuff", binding)` which doesn't reduce repetition as I have to pass binding into every single method.

Comment: did you look http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-concat ?

Comment: I'm a big fan of the `<<` syntax, but do I really want to write `alpha << "\n" << "stuff"`? It doesn't seem very elegant to have to include the "\n" every time

Comment: would you like `["\n","stuff"].inject(alpha,:<<)` ?

Comment: Looks like `alpha` is a collection of lines. You could use an array and invoke `join("\n")`.

Comment: When creating method names, it's important to consider whether they're used in other classes and what their behavior is in those places. `puts` is used to output to a stream, not append to an object/container. Using `puts` to append would be confusing to others who are using your code. `append` or `concat` are more acceptable because other classes that have that method use it to add something to a container. It might seem like a small thing, but it's important to making a language flow as we write in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class String
  def append(apnd)
    concat("\n#{apnd}")
  end
end
```

But I don't think is the right way to do it. I feel code smell in this approach. If you care about ensuring a line break when additional lines are added, then you should care about that even when additional lines are not added. In your case, the endline character should be appended to the previous string, not prepended to the string to be added. From the beginning, you should keep your strings normalized in the sense that they end with an endline character. For this, I have a method in my personal library called `String#unchomp` and `String#unchomp!`:

```
class String
  def unchomp; sub(/#$/?\z/, $/) end
  def unchomp!; sub!(/#$/?\z/, $/) end
end
```

Whenever I need to ensure a string ends with an endline character, I apply this method to it.

Comment: I would go with this one.. +1

Comment: But you made it complete.. For this, I wouldn't prefer like others to include *stdlib* like - `stringio`..

Comment: Question from curiosity - What `/#$/?\z/` is doing here..? I am weak in *regex*...

Comment: It means an optional endline character at the end of the string.

Comment: You should definetly use `{}` for interpolation in a case like this!

Comment: inside `//`, I think `{}` not needed @toro2k.. Is it ?

Comment: @toro2k Why should I need that?

Comment: Because it takes more than a while to recognize the sequence `#$/` not as a part of the regexp but as an interpolation.

Answer (score 4):

You can get close to what you describe using a [`StringIO`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html):

```
require 'stringio'
alpha_io = StringIO.new

alpha_io.puts "lorem ipsum"
alpha_io.puts "more text"
alpha_io.puts "look I'm woody, howdy howdy howdy"

alpha_io.string
# => "lorem ipsum\nmore text\nlook I'm woody, howdy howdy howdy\n"
```

However, if your string is mostly literal, you can get away easily by using a heredoc:

```
alpha = <<-STRING
lorem ipsum
more text
look I'm woody, howdy howdy howdy
Some interpolation #{"here".upcase}
STRING

puts alpha
# lorem ipsum
# more text
# look I'm woody, howdy howdy howdy
# Some interpolation HERE
```

(Even though SO got confused with the syntax, I assure you it's valid ruby ;))

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> alpha = "lorem ipsum"
> alpha = alpha + "\n" + "more text"
> alpha = alpha + "\n" + "look I'm woody, howdy howdy howdy"
> ```
>
> I would like:
>
> ```
> alpha.puts "lorem ipsum"
> alpha.puts "more text"
> alpha.puts "look I'm woody, howdy howdy howdy"
> ```

I would counter that you're on the wrong path; That, instead of concatenating to an string, you're really looking for an array-like behavior, where you can push content onto it, then later output it however you need at that moment.

For instance:

```
alpha = ["lorem ipsum"]
alpha << "more text"
alpha << "look I'm woody, howdy howdy howdy"

puts alpha
# >> lorem ipsum
# >> more text
# >> look I'm woody, howdy howdy howdy
```

Or:

```
alpha.join("\n")
# => "lorem ipsum\nmore text\nlook I'm woody, howdy howdy howdy"
```

If you use a string as your buffer, you're going to paint yourself into corners, especially if you need to modify that buffer later in our code. Keeping it as an array allows you to easily `push`/`pull`, `shift`/`unshift`, `insert`/`delete` or `sort` elements then, when everything is as you want it, simply output it.